# Is this Monad/Applicative Simplfication possible?

Tags: haskell, monads

Is it possible?, (there is a `>>magic` function) to simplify this:

```
insertTransaction :: Day -> Int -> Int -> MyReaderT Bool
insertTransaction day amount price = ....

logTransaction :: Int -> Int -> MyReaderT Bool
logTransaction amount price = do
  day <- currentDay 
  insertTransaction day amount price
```

To this:

```
logTransaction :: Int -> Int -> MyReaderT Bool
logTransaction = currentDay `>>magic` insertTransaction
```

I think there should be one operator like `>>magic` but I can't found it. Nor `<*>` neither `<$>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really possible without typeclass trickery, because you're trying to "lift" a function with an arbitrary number of arguments — which is, of course, not really a well-defined concept in Haskell, due to currying.

The best you're likely to get in standard, readable Haskell is this:

```
logTransaction :: Int -> Int -> MyReaderT Bool
logTransaction amount price = join $ insertTransaction
    <$> currentDay
    <*> pure amount
    <*> pure price
```

I think this is probably fine — the proposed operator seems quite difficult to read to me, since it's hard to tell how many arguments are being processed or where they're going.

With the [Strathclyde Haskell Enhancement](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/pub/she/) preprocessor, `logTransaction` could be written as follows, using [idiom brackets](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/pub/she/idiom.html):

```
logTransaction :: Int -> Int -> MyReaderT Bool
logTransaction amount price = (| insertTransaction currentDay ~amount ~price @ |)
```

Finally, it is *technically* possible to write `logTransaction` in a point-free style, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
logTransaction :: Int -> Int -> MyReaderT Bool
logTransaction = ((currentDay >>=) .) . flip . flip insertTransaction
```

Answer (score 8):

If you wrote `insertTransaction` in the first place, it might make sense to refactor it to

```
insertTransaction :: Int -> Int -> Day -> MyReaderT Bool
insertTransaction amount price day = ....
```

Then you could say

```
logTransaction :: Int -> Int -> MyReaderT Bool
logTransaction amount price = currentDay >>= insertTransaction amount price
```